# project location not trusted in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How to get VS2010 to trust a location and not ask for permission before opening projects from location not trusted? There used to be a .NET 2.0 configuration tool --- is there a .NET 4 equivalent

related to this

[The Project Location is Not Trusted error in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603144/the-project-location-is-not-trusted-error-in-visual-studio)