# System.Web RoleManager in App.Config is missing or invalid during run-time

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-3.5, asp.net-membership, console-application

I am developing a setup program (EXE file) which will deploy and configure an ASP.NET website and corresponding ASP.NET membership database.

I have a console app with the following app.config, which includes a system.web section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer1" connectionString="Server=.\NAME;Database=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=true" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="FileLog" />
          <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
          <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter" />
      <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
      <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider1"
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      cookieName=".ASPROLES"
      cookieTimeout="30"
      cookiePath="/"
      cookieRequireSSL="false"
      cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
      cookieProtection="All" >
      <providers>
        <add
          name="SqlProvider1"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
          connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer1"
          applicationName="SampleApplication" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However, I can't seem to get Roles or Membership to work, no matter what I do to app.config. It's as if the whole system.web section is invalid or missing. Mostly I am getting the below error message, sometimes I get "Roles are not enabled".

[image: Error reading system.web roleManager]

Is it possible to utilize ASP.NET Membership and Roles in a console app? and configured the normal way via system.web section? If so, how? Please note the Visual Studio project is saved on a network share.

**Update - Compiler Settings as requested**

[image]

**Update - Please note it is being run from a network share**

The exception has an inner exception which is a security exception, caused because the solution is on a network share, anyone who can provide a fix for running solutions from network share will get the bounty!

**Update - Exception details as requested**

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
  BareMessage=An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.web/roleManager: Request failed.
  Filename=L:\InternetSharePointRepository\InternetSharePointSolution\InternetSharePointConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\InternetSharePointConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.Config
  Line=34
  Message=An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.web/roleManager: Request failed. (L:\InternetSharePointRepository\InternetSharePointSolution\InternetSharePointConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\InternetSharePointConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.Config line 34)
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Security.Roles.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Security.Roles.EnsureEnabled()
       at System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole(String roleName)
       at InternetSharePointConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main() in L:\InternetSharePointRepository\InternetSharePointSolution\InternetSharePointConsoleApplication1\Module1.vb:line 7
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
       GrantedSet=""
       Message=Request failed.
       PermissionState=<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Level="Minimal"/>
</PermissionSet>

       RefusedSet=""
       Source=mscorlib
       Url=""
       StackTrace:
            at System.Reflection.MethodBase.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandle method, IntPtr parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
            at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.InvokeCtorWithReflectionPermission(ConstructorInfo ctor)
            at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionImpl(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
            at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
            at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)
       InnerException:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to [TrevorBrooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1854345/trevorbrooks) for confirming that Membership and RoleManager sections do work in App.Config and can be used just like in a web application.

However, you may find that exceptions are thrown when debugging or running from a network location - an unusual scenario that was the root cause of my problem. The best workaround I have found is to change the build output path to a path on the local file system - as highlighted in the image below.

[image]

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: This isn't the answer to your original question which was: "Is it possible to utilize ASP.NET Membership and Roles in a console app? and configured the normal way via system.web section? If so, how?"

Comment: True but it says in bold font shortly after "Update it is being run from a network share". Stack Overflow allows you to edit the question, as I have done so now to be more clear. Don't expect to be down voted by someone I awarded a bounty to! Most people would be glad about receiving a bounty?

Comment: Normally two separate questions are two separate posts.

Comment: Don't remember you complaining about that before I awarded you the bounty... You were proposing solutions to the network share issue, with some copying and pasting going on, so why are you giving me a hard time?

Comment: Edit your answer and I'll add it back (can't add it back until you make an edit)

Answer (score 1):

Change the TargetFramework to the normal .Net Framework 4 instead of Client. Client does not include System.Web.  If that's not the issue add the System.Web.dll to your project as a reference. You may have to browse to it.

Also, you'll need to add the Membership section to system.web, something like:

```
<membership defaultProvider=”AspNetSqlProvider”>
 <providers>
 <clear/>
 <add name=”AspNetSqlProvider” connectionStringName=”SqlConnection” type=”System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider”
enablePasswordRetrieval=”false”
enablePasswordReset=”true”
requiresQuestionAndAnswer=”true”
passwordFormat=”Hashed”
applicationName=”TestApp”/>
 </providers>
 </membership>
```

Here's an example of the entire system.web in your config:

```
  <system.web>   
    <roleManager enabled="true">    
        <providers>    
            <clear/>    
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyAspNetDB"     
                applicationName="/SampleRolesApp"     
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />    
        </providers>    
    </roleManager>    
    <membership>    
        <providers>    
            <clear/>    
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"     
                connectionStringName="MyAspNetDB"     
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"     
                enablePasswordReset="true"     
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"     
                applicationName="/SamplesRolesApp"     
                requiresUniqueEmail="false"     
                passwordFormat="Hashed"     
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"     
                minRequiredPasswordLength="7"     
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"     
                passwordAttemptWindow="10"     
                passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""                          
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />    
        </providers>    
    </membership>            
    <authentication mode="Forms" /> 
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done both of those things, I'll double check though. For example, it wouldn't compile if system.web wasn't already referenced, it would error on imports system.web.security and Roles.CreateRole?

Comment: When I created the project I set the target framework to .NET 3.5 because it needs to interface with SharePoint 2010 dlls.

Comment: I don't see the Membership section in your app.config, you'll need to add that.

Comment: Darn it! Just realized it's cuz the solution is on a network share which is causing a security exception. Thanks Microsoft for the clear-as-mud exception message! Your code works by the way, just not when run from a network share.

Comment: I award the bounty to someone before it expires, given that no one else has answered, it will probably be you! I still have the problem running it from a network share, this is the root cause of the exception...

Comment: Yeah can you give me the exact security exception you're getting?

Comment: Actually, this sounds like what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009791/silverlight-project-build-fails-in-vs2010-when-project-is-on-a-mapped-network-dr

Comment: I've added the details of the exception above.

Comment: The only resource I could find on this is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx