# Visual Studio 2010 Projects on a Network

Tags: visual-studio-2010, networking, project

I have a windows form project that runs/debugs fine when the project is located on my local machine but when copied to a network location the run/debug just doesn't work. No error messages are given. Clicking the tool strip button that resembles a green play button briefly turns grey, nothing happens and then it turns back green ready to be pressed again.

When the project is copied from the network onto yet another machine so that it is local again debugging/running can be performed again as expected.

Has anyone any ideas as to why I can't debug/run the project in the visual studio environment when the project sits on a network?

Comment: permissions? non-trusted location?

Comment: Look in the Output window.  Have fun with caspol.exe

Comment: This could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159627/keeping-visual-studio-projects-on-a-network-drive/9482133#9482133