# Visual Studio 2013 hangs/freezes during build, then disconnects Network Drive afterwards

Tags: visual-studio, networking, network-drive

VS is installed locally and project files are kept on our network drive (F:). I read this question [Keeping Visual Studio Projects on a Network Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159627/keeping-visual-studio-projects-on-a-network-drive) but it doesn't explain the issue we're having.

When I try to create a build from the network drive the build hangs and I have to force VS to close. The network drive then disconnects, and when I try to connect in Windows Explorer, the drive is disconnected with "CSC-CACHE" next to the drive. To remap the drive, I've been needing to restart and remap, and even then sometimes the drive is still in the cache mode. During this entire process, I can still ping the drive.

I tried downloading a working copy of the project files to my local computer, which builds and runs fine.

The concerning part is the network drive (F:) has been disconnected on multiple computers. The only way I can recreate the disconnect however, is when I try to build the project in VS using the files from the network drive. Is this an issue with the network drive itself? What should I do to find the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Hmm... if I had to guess, I'd say this isn't a problem with VS itself.  Not that that's awfully helpful to you now!

Comment: Yeah I agree, I'm just not sure how to troubleshoot this further to see why the drive is getting disconnected. Seemed weird to me that VS was kicking it off, but accessing the files through Windows Explorer doesn't.

Comment: Definitely weird; The part that makes me guess it's still related to the drive/OS/network is that it happens on multiple computers. Is there maybe another network location you could test it on? Also maybe check if there are relevant errors on the box hosting that drive.

Comment: This question is getting the chicken before the egg.  The drive isn't getting unmapped because the compiler froze, the compiler hangs because the drive got unmapped.  Clearly you'll need a more reliable network connection to do this.  That isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path instead of drive mapping.

I started [similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990954/visual-studio-2012-freezes-while-adding-a-new-asp-net-mvc-controller) (well, my drive remains connected) and hope this advice can help in you case.