# Visual studio + explore sftp

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-2013, sftp

I'm looking for a way to develope using Visual studio 2013 on a remote server, using only sftp/ssh(browsing the remote folder in solution explorer, and uploding file using ctrl+s).
I know it's possible to open a simple ftp site using File>Open Websit, but that dose not suppors sftp.

Dose anyone know of a addon/plugin for that?

10x!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I finally came up with an answer to this question.
I found this sftp to ftp tunnle, which I installd locally, and simply connect Visual studio to ftp on 127.0.0.1:

http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download

10x a lot!

Comment: How did you get this to work? Do you run `devenv.exe` each time you want to edit a file?

Answer (score 2):

While this will be possible, you are likely going to have a poor development experience.  Visual Studio does a lot of File IO during compilation so the latency sftp will inevitably introduce is going to make this quite slow.

To get going, you'll need a way to mount a sftp share in windows.  A quick google search turned this up: http://sumtips.com/2011/09/mount-ftp-sftp-server-as-drive.html which details how to use [SFTP Net Drive](http://download.cnet.com/SFTP-Net-Drive/3000-7240_4-75654355.html).  (If that doesn't work, you might want to check [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), or ask the question there.

Once you have your SFTP mounted as a drive in Windows, this SO thread discusses using Visual Studio: [Keeping Visual Studio Projects on a Network Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159627/keeping-visual-studio-projects-on-a-network-drive) including modifications you'll need to make for [permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I actually tryed that, and I had performance issues even without compiling anything, just by mounting a large directory.
I was hoping there is a plugin that could be used within VS, and only download and upload files.
I mostly develop web client side, so I complie projects rarely.

Answer (score 1):

Tamir SharpSSH is what i use. seems to work pretty well.