# visual studio removes backslash from path, generated by cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Sorry for my English. I try to generate local Visual Studio project from shared (Samba) sources and libs. I have linker error: "cannot open file \samba_path\somelib.lib". Real path is "\\samba_path\somelib.lib". It's valid path, that I see in linker settings in Visual Studio and in Cmake variables. Why linker don't understand this path?

Comment: Have you tried setting `\\\\samba_path/somelib.lib` as the path? Alternatively try connecting a network drive to the samba drive and use `Z:\somelib.lib`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't use [UNC paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention).  If your Visual Studio version - or any other tool used by it - does not support it, it can't open the files on that network drive. Map your `samba_path` to a drive letter. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159627/keeping-visual-studio-projects-on-a-network-drive).