# TNS-12560 error from .NET app on network drive

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle11g

I have a .NET application that I work on from time to time. I run the IDE (I have tried VB2008, VS2010 and VS2012) on a windows 7 computer.

When I have the solution (project) on my local hard drive it runs in debug mode from the IDE swimmingly. If however I have the solution on a network drive I get TNS-12560.

Spent 2.5 days with Oracle tech support to find out that moving it to my local disk works. They now claim that is the solution.

This is not the solution, I am hoping someone here has the solution.

I am running Oracle 11g r2 (11.2.0.4.0) 32 bit client.

BTW this used to work without any problem. I do not know if MS or Oracle is messing with me.

EDIT - **This problem is totally related to the VB.NET solution being on a network drive vs the VB.NET solution being on the local hard drive. If I run the IDE and connect to the solution on the network drive it fails, if I connect to the exact same solution on the local hard disk (C:) it works fine.**

Comment: Have checked out this article yet: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12560_tns_protocol_adapter_error.htm?

Comment: I have run through all of the standard stuff before I called Oracle. TNSNames and SQLNet.ora files are fine. TNSPING and SQLPLUS work fine when connecting to the same DB, VB.NET works fine when the solution is on the same machine as the IDE, but if the solution is on a mapped network drive, I get the error.

Comment: Perhaps the software on the mapped network drive cannot find the tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: Prescott, if that is the case, why? The software is running in the VS IDE on my local computer where the tnsnames.ora lives. Up until a recently (Don't know when cause I don't work on this often) this worked fine. As part of my testing I created a "clean" W7 VM, installed just Oracle 32 bit client and VS, and it exhibits the same issue.

Comment: Mapped drives have always been problematic for Oracle, however that usually applied to the database, not client software.  Off the top of my head I can't remember the exact issue.  I ran into this exact issue before, years ago and the reason why has left my memory.  There's a disconnect here, that's obvious, if I remember correctly it's a Oracle.DataAccess.dll issue.  Check to see if it's copied out to the bin folder of the software, if it isn't, manually copy it out.  Frustrating, I know, hang in there ... I'm looking in my old code, perhaps it'll spark my memory.

Comment: Just for giggles, when you run VS, right click on the launch icon and select "Run as Administrator".  There was an issue with mapped drives with Vista (ouch, Vista is still a painful memory) some years back that had to do with profiles getting lost one to another.

Comment: Have you seen the info at this link?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159627/keeping-visual-studio-projects-on-a-network-drive

Answer (score -1):

Typically TNS-12560 indicates an error connecting the client to the database listener.  Given that it connects on the local machine tells me that the listener on the database you are trying to connect to is up and configured properly to connect to the database.  So the issue is on the machine you want to run the software on.  You say it has always worked before, so that tells me that the TNS configuration has either been changed or the machine you want to run the software on can no longer reach the database machine on the network.  From the machine you want to run the software on, can you ping the database server?  If not, then it is unreachable by TNS too and you need to figure out why it's not reachable.  If you can ping it, then there is an configuration issue with TNS.  On the machine you want to run the software on, use windows explorer to navigate to the TNS configuration folder (Oracle would never tell you to do this, they would tell you to use the TNS configuration tool).  The TNS configuration folder is typically found in C:\app\username\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin, where `username` is the user profile that the client was installed under.  In there is a file named tnsnames.ora.  This file is a simple text file in a specific format that tells the client where on the network the database is.  For example, my tnsnames.ora contains:

```
DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.38)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

There are three pieces of information that define the connection to the database, the IP address of the machine the database resides on (`host = 192.168.10.38`), the name of the listener (`SERVICE_NAME = orcl`) and the port the listener is listening on (`PORT = 1521`).  You will need to confirm that the information is correct for your database.

Comment: The reason I dinged this answer is because I stated above I had checked all of this. The only thing needed to make things work is to move the "solution" from a network drive to a local drive. I do not make any changes to any oracle stuff at all. If I had to guess I believe the problem began when I installed the latest version of the Oracle clientOracle 11g r2 (11.2.0.4.0) 32 bit.

Comment: When you run the project from a network drive, the solution is looking for the Oracle client on a relative path, if you do not have the client installed on the machine that is hosting the network drive, you will not be able to connect to the database.  Check the <applicationName>.vbproj file in the application directory, it is pointing to the client on a relative path, I haven't tried this but maybe if you edit the vbproj file to point to the local machine's Oracle client it might work.