# SCons: Not able to build using network drive

Tags: python, visual-studio, scons

I'am trying to build using SCons.
everything works fine while building on local machine, but I am trying to build same source located on network drive build fails.
Error: the application was unable to start correctly (0xc00003b). Click OK to close the application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0gv4.png)

Comment: SCons: Not able to build using network drive not dive

Comment: How is the drive referenced? Via \\machine\share, or as a mapped drive? (BTW.. I think you can edit the title to correct dive to drive)

Comment: Hi,

I solved the problem by below adaptation:
for Visual Studio 2010, copied mspdb100.dll & mspdbsrv.exe from VisualStudio2010\Common7\IDE to VisualStudio2010\VC\bin

for Visual Studio 2005, copied mspdb80.dll & mspdbsrv.exe from VisualStudio2005\Common7\IDE to VisualStudio2005\VC\bin

I am opening the command line for network drive from my local machine  (which contain a Visual Studio installation) and the source is located on a remote PC(network drive).

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of that file copying.  Sounds like the PATH wasn't properly set when you tried compile against the network location.  Did you cd to the network path?  You didn't answer my initial questions.

Comment: 1. Drive is shared and I tried UNC path mapping in many way but that didn't solved the problem.
2. I tried to create a dummy visual studio project on network drive and got warning, 
Visual Studio examined the network folder is not suitable, the directory is on network share or drive mapped to a network share.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10217072/82681 someone else had non-scons related issue with vs2010 and network share..